# GWT best cell widget/table to populate columns?

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I am creating a GWT app that will use a table to display some data. I am not sure which cell widget/table to use to populate data vertically in column. Basically I want to populate data going down instead of going across.

Simple example:

```
Category A   |  Category B
-------------|-------------
item 1a      |  item 1b
item 2a      |  item 2b

...
```

Based of off the showcase of feaures: 
http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

My best option might be to just use a grid, or to create a bunch of separate cell tables for each category. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look like 2 separate CellList's to me.  The CellTable and DataGrid objects are specifically bound to displaying object data in rows.

Comment: Ok thank you, that's what I was unsure of; whether or not you could hack something together so that CellTables or DataGrids could display data in something other than rows.

Answer (score 1):

`My best option might be to just use a grid, or to create a bunch of separate cell tables for each category. Anyone have any ideas?`

If you want to show just data then better to use [FlexTable](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFlexTable) for it. it is same as table of html.

[Cell Table](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) is manage large amounts of data and having inbuilt cell like editable, selection cell etc...widgets in it. so it is reach feature with it.

[Data Grid](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) is same as celltable but with fixed header and footer, with a scrollable content area